# fatal error: 'openssl/bn.h' file not found on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: compiling, openssl, linux-headers

I did OpenSSL setup referencing [How to install OpenSSL 1.1.1 and libSSL package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126893/how-to-install-openssl-1-1-1-and-libssl-package) on windows subsystem **Ubuntu 18.04**. Writing CPP file in which using OpenSSL files:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
```

When compile, It is giving me an error:

```
fatal error: 'openssl/bn.h' file not found
```

If I check, this file exists in `/usr/include/openssl/` and `/opt/openssl/include/openssl`. New to such errors, please help.

Edit:

I am writing a EOSIO smart contract in which I am including the above file. And when compiling using:

```
eosio-cpp catcatshamir.cpp -o catcatshamir.abi
```

Getting the above errors.
EOS files are stored here `/usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.7.0/include` and no errors for included header files from here.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are probably missing libssl-dev.

```
  sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: This is already installed. If I try again, it returns `libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.1.1g-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).`

Comment: Can you install sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev

Comment: It returns, `libcurl4-openssl-dev is already the newest version (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.12).`